# Raw Input an alternative keyboard hook?

Tags: c++, winapi, input, keyboard, hook

Quick question --

I was reading about keyboard hooks and one suggested using Raw Input to do this, yet I havn't found any example of it. 
For example I am using

```
RAWINPUTDEVICE rid[1];
rid[0].usUsagePage = 0x01;
rid[0].usUsage = 0x06;
rid[0].hwndTarget = hWnd;
rid[0].dwFlags = 0;
RegisterRawInputDevices(rid, 1, sizeof(rid[0]));
```

And catchign WM_INPUT fine in the applications own window, but not outside the application. Is this possible outside the application or do you have to use WH_KEYBOARD or WH_KEYBOARD_LL? MSDN didn't make it clear if Raw Input could be made globally.

EDIT: I know about Hooks but I want to know if you can do it with Raw input too!

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Windows hook is mechanism that one can use to intercept events before they reach an application. Filter functions (functions that receive events) are classified according to the event type. If one wants to attach to a Windows hook, the filter function has to be installed using `SetWindowsHookEx`. I have to mention that global hooks must be in a separate dll file. You can read more about hooks in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644959%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: I am talking about Raw Input, not Hooks

Comment: Understood, especially after you edited a question :)
I think that raw input messages are available only in your application, not globally. If you want to filter messages globally, I think you'll have to use hooks...

Comment: Actually you can use RIDEV_INPUTSINK to receive all keyboard input regardless of focus.

Answer (score 10):

Looking at [the MSDN documentation for that stuff](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645565.aspx), there is a flag called `RIDEV_INPUTSINK` which is described as: "If set, this enables the caller to receive the input even when the caller is not in the foreground."

I haven't messed with that myself, but it sounds like it could be useful for getting input from beyond the application's window.

Comment: @KaiserJohaan make this the accepted best answer as it is the correct solution to your question. I have used it on multiple occasions.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I initialize `RAW INPUT` to globally intercept mouse and keyboard events. The great advantage compared to hooks is you don't need a DLL. 
You treats the raw input events in the window procedure with `WM_INPUT`. For further informations : [RAW INPUT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645536(v=vs.85).aspx)

```
#include <Windows.h>

const USHORT HID_MOUSE    = 2;
const USHORT HID_KEYBOARD = 6;

bool HID_RegisterDevice(HWND hTarget, USHORT usage)
{
    RAWINPUTDEVICE hid;
    hid.usUsagePage = 1;
    hid.usUsage = usage;
    hid.dwFlags = RIDEV_DEVNOTIFY | RIDEV_INPUTSINK;
    hid.hwndTarget = hTarget;

    return !!RegisterRawInputDevices(&hid, 1, sizeof(RAWINPUTDEVICE));
}

void HID_UnregisterDevice(USHORT usage)
{
    RAWINPUTDEVICE hid;
    hid.usUsagePage = 1;
    hid.usUsage = usage;
    hid.dwFlags = RIDEV_REMOVE;
    hid.hwndTarget = NULL;

    RegisterRawInputDevices(&hid, 1, sizeof(RAWINPUTDEVICE));
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE, LPSTR cmd_line, int cmd_show)
{
    WNDCLASS wc;
    ...
    RegisterClass(&wc);

    HWND hwnd = CreateWindow(...);
    ...

    HID_RegisterDevice(hwnd, HID_KEYBOARD);
    HID_RegisterDevice(hwnd, HID_MOUSE);

    MSG msg;
    while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        ...
    }

    HID_UnregisterDevice(HID_MOUSE);
    HID_UnregisterDevice(HID_KEYBOARD);

    return (int) msg.wParam;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure exactly about raw input, but for keyboard hook in general you need to make it a dll and register in system so it will be loaded by every process. some details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in remarks

Comment: Neither `WH_KEYBOARD` nor `WH_KEYBOARD_LL` need to be placed in a DLL. Besides, the question is asking about Raw Input, and Raw Input can monitor system-wide input events.